# Input to move player camera around not working

Tags: unity-game-engine

in my update loop i put:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && (Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") != 0 || Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") != 0))
        {
            yAxis = rig.y_axis.localRotation;
            xAxis = rig.x_axis.localRotation;
            LookRotation();
        }
```

It only registers once every click
any help?

i tried removing the last part past the && and it still does not work

Comment: What exactly where you expecting? Have you read the docs on those functions?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.